# what sort of switch can I use?

Tags: mosfet, switches

Noob here, with a basic question.
I am looking for a switch to close a circuit not straight to ground. P channel MOSFET seems fitting, but I would like one where to keep the switch open, it does not consume power.

My problem in more detail:
I just redid a battery powered arduino project incorporating a wake on shake from sparkfun. It is a 5V node, used to be on a 6V battery, that I now replaced with a 3.7V and I am regulating to 5V for the node. I had battery level reporting by having two resistors hooked up to an analogue pin to ground pin and raw pin respectively. Now, I would like to do the same for battery (connect the 3.7V positive to the same pin with a different resistor), but not constantly, only switch this circuit on by the arduino at certain intervals.

Please, point me in the right direction, how to best tackle it.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you please add a schematic of the described problem.

Comment: Closing this, please provide a schematic of your ideas and/or make your question a little more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino pins set as INPUT does not eat much current, when you do not read them.

If you are not to go for power-save sleep modes and similar technics, you are probably good just to connect one resistor between  3.7V and analog pin, then other between analog pin and digital (or analog) pin. Set the other pin as INPUT and it would be high resistance and nearly no current will go.

When you want to read voltage, set the digital pin to OUTPUT and LOW and you have ground. Wait for a moment to things to set (I do not know, like delay(5) or so), read the analog pin and sent the digital to INPUT again (and you do not consume power again).

Other solutions may be much harder, need other circuits (like relay) and even if such circuits  would not eat power in disconected state, the cost (in power spend) of switching them may be higher, than the minimal power consumed this way. (Especially when you need a pin for managing the switch anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much! This sounds really smart and very simple. I will try and will be back, if I run into any issues. Your help is most appreciated!